# Devise messages still display when i go to other page and go back through back button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, message

i have a problem about devise messages. When i sign in into my page, a notice messages "welcome to my blogs" show up and if i go to another page and go back through button back in browser, i still got this message, how to make is disappear? I know we can do it by refresh any page when back button pressed, but i don't want to do that, any one have another ideal for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't do a check to dismiss this notification upon user logged in. 
You can check this link on how to do that. https://coderwall.com/p/b5lhog/ignore-turn-off-devise-config-reconfirmable-while-saving-email-in-update-action

To style your notification as well you need this. I have used this video multiple times on different projects. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87fBAWc25Sk

Comment: may be you misunderstand me, when i sign in and go to other page, this notification wont show up but when i use back button to go back , notification show up again, it look like this:
`login_page -> dashboard -> another page -> back to dashboard by back button ||
notify show in dashboard -> notify not show in other page -> notify show again in dashboard`

Comment: Check the tutorial I sent you. Everything is there. This is just a simple if-else procedure. You need to edit the :notice tag in your application.html.erb which was inserted there when you installed devise.